# Dropdown Menu not displaying in Body when in Iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to make it so that I only have to update one page for my menu bar. This is an intranet page for internal use only. I don't wish to use PHP.

The issue I am having is that once I scroll over the menu tab and the dropdowns show they are stuck in the iframe and will not flow onto the main page.

Is there any way to fix this so that someone wont need to scroll through the iframe just to click the menu tab.

```
 <body>
 <iframe frameborder="0" height="260px" width="100%" src="Navigation.html" name="iframe_a" allowfullscreen wmode="transparent"></iframe>
 <p style="font-family: Arial; text-align: center;" class="MsoNormal"><b><span style="font-size: 18pt;">NEW SPECIFICATIONS AND UPDATES</span></b></p>
 <p style="font-family: Arial; text-align: center;" class="MsoNormal"><b><span style="font-size: 18pt;"></span></b></p>
 <span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Arial;"><big>Please be advise the December 2015 update for Traffic Control (TC) Signs has been released.</big><br>
 <br>
 </span>
```

Your thought on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have also tried to use the below with no luck. Nothing shows up.

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Navigation").load("Navigation.html");
    });
</script>

Comment: Iframes are made in order to define an exact space on your website and the page you are showing inside will only show inside of that space. It's like telling that page "my screen has x width and y height" when it's only part of the website. That's why i don't think that's possible using Iframes.